# How would you define a Map of Map structure?

Tags: data-structures

I've recently implemented a piece of work that relied on a Map of Map structure, simply because I needed two keys to pointed to a single value. To my understanding, dictionaries conceptually should use a single key per value to map the entire thing.

What would a proper data structure be for a pair of keys pointing to a single value? Which kind of collections would you use in Java or C++ to achieve this, for example?

Comment: `map <map <int, int>, int> m;` is a thing.

Comment: Well yes, it works just fine. I was mostly wondering if there is a way better accepted by literature

Comment: If you're asking from a language-agnostic point of view, there's no reason why a key can't consist of 2 (or more) numbers, strings or whatever else. You just need some way to combine them into one logical key. As for both Java and C++, you can use any object consisting of whatever you want as keys for a map (as long as you implement the correct hash or comparison interfaces).

Comment: This question is too broad for this site as it stands. If it's a theoretical question, you'll need to specify what type of map you're talking about - you can use a binary search tree, a hash table or something else. Although you'd need to show a good understanding of how those things work in your question, as needing to also explain those concepts would make answers too long. If it's a language-specific question, your question should be specific to one language. In either case, an example of what you're trying to do would help, as explanations aren't always entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a practical example: values of a function in certain integer points on a two-dimensional plane. So the function is `f : (int x, int y) -> double value`.

1. The straighforward way is to pack all arguments in a `struct`.
   In this example, it means the function maps points to values, and a point is a `pair` of two `int`s, or a custom `struct Point` with two `int` fields or getters if needed.
   So the data structure is `map <Point, double> f`, where `Point` can be `pair <int, int>` in the simple case.
2. We can also say that the function is a mapping from `int x` to a family of one-argument functions, which map `int y` to a `double value`.
   The data structure will then look as follows: `map <int, map <int, double> > f`.

The choice depends on the function you are modeling, and maybe on performance considerations.